# Mongo Atlas Random Message: "BadValue: SCRAM-SHA-256 authentication is disabled"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm getting the following random message on my Mongo Atlas "Access History" view:

"FAILED BadValue: SCRAM-SHA-256 authentication is disabled"

This message is attached to my application IP hosted at AWS. I basically got this message first and then the success message at the same timestamp.

- Instance MongoAtlas - Cluster Tier M40 General
- Replica Set - 3 nodes
- Driver mongoose: “^6.5.1”
- Mongo version as per Atlas view: 5.0.12
- Mongo String URI: mongodb+srv://xyz:ABCDEFGH@clusterabc.abcde.mongodb.net/my_db

Is that an issue while connecting to Mongo?